# Pass View Model into a Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewmodel

Is there a way to pass a view model(s) into a function?

We have the following code

```
Activity a = new Activity();
a.memID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? 0 : WebSessions.MemID;
a.caseUserID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? WebSessions.CUserID : 0;
a.isMember = !(WebSessions.IsCUser); 
a.isUser = (WebSessions.IsCUser);
```

Also

```
OpenTask o = new OpenTask();
o.memID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? 0 : WebSessions.MemID;
o.caseUserID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? WebSessions.CUserID : 0;
o.isMember = !(WebSessions.IsCUser); 
o.isUser = (WebSessions.IsCUser);
```

I would like to create a function that sets these values for me

```
GetValuesForUserORMember(*pass in view model*)
{
    thisView = *pass in view model*

    thisView.memID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? 0 : WebSessions.MemID;
    thisView.caseUserID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? WebSessions.CUserID : 0;
    thisView.isMember = !(WebSessions.IsCUser); 
    thisView.isUser = (WebSessions.IsCUser);
}
```

The use it to do Insert or Update

```
Activity a = new Activity();
a.ID = cID;
a.ActivityModDate = date;
GetValuesForUserORMember(a) <---function
ctx.AddToActivities(a);
ctx.SaveChanges();


OpenTask o = new OpenTask();
o.ID = cID;
o.TaskCompletedDate = date;
o.TaskAssingedTo = uID;
GetValuesForUserORMember(o) <---function
ctx.AddToActivities(o);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

these (4) fields are the exact same for each table/view model (Activity and OpenTask). However there are OTHER fields that are not the same in each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they don't share a base class or interface, you could use dynamic to do it:

```
GetValuesForUserORMember(dynamic thisView)
{
    thisView.memID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? 0 : WebSessions.MemID;
    thisView.caseUserID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? WebSessions.CUserID : 0;
    thisView.isMember = !(WebSessions.IsCUser); 
    thisView.isUser = (WebSessions.IsCUser);
}
```

Comment: Assuming he's working in .NET 4. But a nice touch for using dynamics.

Comment: Well, yeah - you do have to be using the version that supports this solution (or any other) for it to work.  But, seeing as how C# 4 is 1.5 years old right now, and a specific version isn't mentioned - I'm going to assume "current". That said, in case anyone's unclear, dynamics were introduced in C# 4 - so if your compiler tells you it doesn't know what dynamic is, you can't use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your problem is because the types are different? If so, then you can either create an interface that both objects inherit from, or you can create a baseclass (or both). Then you can create the method as you described, where the expected parameter is that of your interface or base class. You will then be able to pass in any object that inherits from this type.

In fact, you could possibly create the base class in such a way that it.

OR, you could use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) to do this, however you will lose any static type checking benefits. If you have control over your classes, I would not suggest this, as .NET is a static language. It is only for edge case convenience that they added this type. But, then again that is just my opinion on dynamic

Example:

```
//This is the base class option, but you could use an interface
//If you encapsulate the FillProperties method it should be in a base class, though
public class BaseViewModel
{
    int memID {get;set;}
    int caseUserID {get;set;}
    bool isMember {get;set;}
    bool isUser {get;set;}

    public void FillProperties()
    //These actions could also possibly be done on the fly in the properties
    {
        memID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? 0 : WebSessions.MemID;
        caseUserID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? WebSessions.CUserID : 0;
        isMember = !(WebSessions.IsCUser); 
        isUser = (WebSessions.IsCUser);
    }
}

public class Activity : BaseViewModel
{
    //additional properties for Activity only
}

public class OpenTask : BaseViewModel
{
    //additional properties for OpenTask only
}
```

Then you could just call it like this

```
var activity = new Activity();
activity.FillProperties();
```

Or, you could remove FillProperties into another class as you described, and do something like this:

```
GetValuesForUserORMember(BaseViewModel thisView)
{
    thisView.memID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? 0 : WebSessions.MemID;
    thisView.caseUserID = (WebSessions.IsCUser) ? WebSessions.CUserID : 0;
    thisView.isMember = !(WebSessions.IsCUser); 
    thisView.isUser = (WebSessions.IsCUser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question good. But if Activity and OpenTask have the same properties that needs to be filled in your method, you should create a base class containing the properties and inherit both from that class.
You can then use the BaseClass type as parameter in your method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like only one thing you need is a common interface for ViewModel classes which encapsulates all fields you are going to set in the method.

```
// Define better name yourself
// I believe IViewModel is pretty generic for your case
public interface IViewModel
{
   int memId { get; set; }
   int caseUserID { get; set; }
   bool isMember  { get; set; }
   bool isUser { get; set; }
}

class Activity : IViewModel
{ ... }

class OpenTask : IViewModel
{ ... }
```

And finally the method:

```
void SetValuesForUserORMember(IViewModel viewModel)
{
    viewModel.memID = WebSessions.IsCUser ? 0 : WebSessions.MemID;
    viewModel.caseUserID = WebSessions.IsCUser ? WebSessions.CUserID : 0;
    viewModel.isMember = !WebSessions.IsCUser; 
    viewModel.isUser = WebSessions.IsCUser;
}
```

---

As alternative solution you can define this method in a common interface and pass in `WebSessions`:

```
interface IViewModelBuilder
{
    void UpdateUserAndMembeDetails(WebSession sessions);
}

void UpdateUserAndMembeDetails(WebSessions ws)
{
    this.memID = ws.IsCUser ? 0 : ws.MemID;
    this.caseUserID = ws.IsCUser ? ws.CUserID : 0;
    this.isMember = !ws.IsCUser; 
    this.isUser = ws.IsCUser;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass a view model into a function as a parameter.  You should implement the same function within each view model to support the Update().  Also as you can imagine, you will need to override your function for each kind of view model to support the different kinds of view model params being passed in.  I would suggest thinking of doing it differently